# How jquery plugin difference between multiple instances of themselves on the same page

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I.e I have a partial view in MVC Asp.net project with loads of javascript inside , now when I perform an action most of javascript is aided by jquery and is using classes. 
The same event's start occurring on multiple instances of the same user control on the page.

So the problem which I have currently is how to uniquely identify from which user control this event is getting called from and hence I would have scope of where to perform the actions on the page. I don't want to use individual Id's for the same impact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure to understand what you mean. But if you mean you have some objects, let's say with the same class 'myClass', and want to know which object calls an action, i think you need to have an id for each object but you will keep the class as jQuery selector and use jQuery.attr(id) to read the id of the object